# Tomcat process not closing

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, tomcat8

i have problem with tomcat not closing after running shutdown.sh. I have profiled the server using the Jconsole and made an thread dump. Normally server runs about 120 processes, and if it doesn't close after running shutdown.sh it keeps about 30 threads. This happens randomly, mainly if Tomcat is running for longer time. We are using tomcat 8.5.28, I'm suspecting Google Firebase client for that behaviour. Maybe you have some idea what may cause the problem? Or have clues what can i do to try finding solution?

Thread dump:
http://textuploader.com/dzjc5

Comment: few libraries are/was known to be hard to close, probably based singletons. Ehcache, Derby DB etc ...

Comment: Thank you for answer, i will investigate if Ehcache is closed properly. At first glance it looks ok  - net.sf.ehcache.constructs.web.ShutdownListener is registred in web.xml

Comment: few, not only one. Characteristic scenario: when undeploy WAR from tomcar console, this libraries reamain in WEB-INF/lib

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps mention in the link.

http://faizakram.com/blog/kill-tomcat-service-running-on-any-port/

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Currently we are killing the process this way if it doesn't close, but we would like to find the solution for this problem on the server/application side.